# SQLite query difficulty

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a SQLite db with three relational tables. I'm trying to return the max record from a log table along with related columns from the other tables based on the ID relationships.

I created the query in DB Browser and verified it returns the expected record however, when I use the exact same query statement in my python code it never steps into the 'for' loop.

SQL statement in python -

```
def GetLastLogEntry():
    readings = ()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT f.FoodCategory, f.FoodName, gs.FoodWeight, 
    gsl.GrillDateTime, gsl.CurrentGrillTemp, gsl.TargetGrillTemp, 
    gsl.CurrentFoodTemp, gsl.TargetFoodTemp, gsl.CurrentOutsideTemp, 
    gsl.CurrentOutsideHumidity FROM Food as f, GrillSession as gs, 
    GrillSessionLog as gsl WHERE f.FoodId = gs.FoodId AND 
    gs.GrillSessionID = gsl.GrillSessionID AND gsl.GrillSessionLogID = 
    (SELECT MAX(GrillSessionLog.GrillSessionLogID) FROM 
    GrillSessionLog, GrillSession WHERE GrillSessionLog.GrillSessionID 
    = GrillSession.GrillSessionID AND GrillSession.ActiveSession = 
    1)")
    for row in cursor:
        print("In for loop")
        readings = readings + (row['FoodCategory'], row['FoodName'])
        print("Food Cat = " + row['FoodCategory'])
    cursor.close()
    return readings
```

The query in DB Browser returns only one row which is what I'm trying to have happen in the python code.

Comment: You haven't called the function? Also, try `for row in cursor.fetchall():`

Comment: It would be inefficient but I suppose I could build the desired output by combining the results of two separate queries...

Comment: @roganjosh - I'm calling this particular Function from the main .py file -

def CurrentSession():
    readings = pConn.GetLastLogEntry()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered the issue....

Using DB Browser, I updated a record I'm using for testing but failed to "write" the change to the database table. As a result, every time I was executing my python code against the table it was executing the query with the original record values because my change wasn't yet committed via DB Browser.

Huge brain fart on that one.... Hopefully it will be a lesson learned for someone else in the future.